# Is this right way when using HTML table in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom

Is this right way when using HTML table in JavaScript?

I have to creating html table as dynamic but i have no idea.

Please tell me a good idea!

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>row1</td>
    <td>val1</td>
    <td>val2</td>
    <td>val3</td>
    <td>val4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row2</td>
    <td>val1</td>
    <td>val2</td>
    <td>val3</td>
    <td>val4</td>
  </tr>
  ...
</tbody>


var tableArr = {
  row1: [],
  row2: [],
};

tableArr.row1.push('1');
tableArr.row1.push('2');
tableArr.row1.push('3');
tableArr.row1.push('4');

tableArr.row2.push('1');
tableArr.row2.push('2');
tableArr.row2.push('3');
tableArr.row2.push('4');

for (var row in tableArr) {
    console.log(row);
    for (var i=0; i<tableArr[row].length; i++) {
        console.log(tableArr[row][i]);
    }
}
```

Please tell me a good idea! :D

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript methods to create table and rows etc.

```js
var tableRef = document.createElement('table');
for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
  var newRow = tableRef.insertRow(i);
  var newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
  var newText = document.createTextNode('New top row #' + i);

  newCell.appendChild(newText);
}
document.body.appendChild(tableRef);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) and modify [HTMLTableElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement) in order to chage HTML tables from JavaScript.

Your initial HTML code:

```
<table id="myTable">
</table>
```

Your JavaScript code:

```
// Find a <table> element with id="myTable":
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

// Create an empty <tr> element and add it to the 1st position of the table:
var row = table.insertRow(0);

// Insert new cells (<td> elements) at the 1st and 2nd position of the "new" <tr> element:
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

// Add some text to the new cells:
cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
```

Your HTML code after JavaScript updates:

```
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
<td>NEW CELL1</td>
<td>NEW CELL2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```